# How do advanced search options work on Cambridge Core?

Tags: publications, databases

I am trying to conduct a publication search on the [Cambridge Core database](https://www.cambridge.org/core) but do not understand how the logical operators and quotation marks work on that site (and even if they do).

Here's an example of my problem:

- If I search for: **(Topological) OR (Data)** I get **133326 results**.
- If I then search for **(Topological) AND (Data)** I'd expect to get LESS results (since I'm looking for the papers which mention **both terms**. Instead I get the same **133326 results**.
- If I add quotation marks: **("Topological") OR ("Data")**, the search yields just **36 results**. I feel like adding quotation marks in this case shouldn't even affect the number of results.
- Finally, running with AND and quotation marks yields more than the above search! **("Topological") AND ("Data")** yielded **1866 results**.

Does anyone know how this works? I couldn't find information on their website.

Comment: FWIW, it does not seem that it supports the usual search tools. Quotation marks work, but looking for `"Algebraic" OR "topology"` has only yielded 8 results, all of which had `OR` in the title. Without quotes, it works better, but nor `OR` or `AND` works. Pipe operator does not work, either. It seems you can only search separately `topological`, `data`, and `topological data` and build the Venn diagram yourself. [User guide](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-file-manager/file/57f641b7000ca2530629e0aa/Core-Userguide-web.pdf) has no mention of advanced search tools, either.

Comment: @Lodinn I thought that might be the case. Thank you anyway for your advice